# MongoDB C# changing replica set config

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using the C# driver to work with MongoDB. I need to use my program to update the set config during execution, and then allow other parts of the program to continue using the driver.

My current issue is reconfiguring the driver to use the new set.

```
try
{
    var res = Database.Admin.RunCommand(new CommandDocument("replSetReconfig", replicaSetConfig));
}
catch (EndOfStreamException){}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.Exc("Problem updating replica set", e);
    ranCommand = false;
}
if (ranCommand)
{
HERE - I need to update the MongoClient or MongoServer to have the new servers
    return;
}
```

I assume when an EndOfStreamException occurs, that the command has been successful, as the server has shutdown/started a reconfig.

I'd like to update the driver to have the new config to ensure that it will definitely reconnect to at least one of the servers, in any edge cases where changing the config will prevent it connecting back with its original connection string.

Is there any way to achieve this?

As an extra question, is there any way from C# to determine the current replica set config version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can answer part 2 of your question - you can query the local database to get the current replica set configuration:

```
MongoServer server = client.GetServer();
var local = server.GetDatabase("local"); 
var collection = local.GetCollection("system.replset");
var cfg = collection.FindOne(); 
Console.WriteLine(cfg["version"]);
```

I would imagine that if the original connection string is no longer valid, you need to create a new MongoClient object with a new connection string.

[Later]
You can also get everything else about the replica set, including its status, by running the replSetGetStatus command on the admin database.